# Determine Windows Version, Edition and Service Pack OF AN OFFLINE DISK IMAGE

Tags: windows, version, registry

Using the registry alone, how does one detect: The Windows Version (XP, Vista, 7). The Edition (Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate). And The Service Pack level (Beta, RTM, SP1, SP2).

This is because I am repairing on offline system. The Registry of offline systems can be mounted and accessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **values** under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`. I presume you know where to find that hive?! The respective hive can be found under `%SystemRoot%\System32\config` with the name `SOFTWARE`.

Side-note: you can attempt to verify your results by looking at some well-known files (e.g. `kernel32.dll`, `ntdll.dll`) and into their version information resource (what you're looking for is the file version: with, e.g. `GetFileVersionInfo()`).

Edition values, if that's needed, can be found at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions`. See [here](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/06/15/having-fun-with-windows-licensing/).

Comment: To load a hive you use `regedit`. You can do this from any Windows machine and should not affect your installation. Just load the hive and choose some temporary name for a new branch. More here:
http://www.zeda.nl/index.php/en/load-user-registry-hive-in-regedit

Comment: `If gpedit.msc is missing in system 32 folder it is home.` https://superuser.com/questions/1325305/get-windows-version-information-from-hard-drive#comment1976837_1325317

Answer (score 1):

Everything you want is in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`.

However, I believe *these values can be faked*, so be cautious.

Comment: EditionID, CSDVersion, BuildLab, Product Name, etc... there's a lot of redundancy there, and I think none of them is foolproof. Probably the most descriptive is BuildLab; for me it's: `7601.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850`. You'll still need EditionID though (`HomePremium`, etc.).

Comment: is there a better way then? like querying the file version of some *what* system file?

Comment: the latter can be found at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions`

Comment: @unixman83: Querying files (@STATUS's solution) will work for most things, but not for the edition (Home Premium vs Ultimate).

Comment: @unixman83: any well-known file will work. Make sure to verify it's a signed (and valid) version of the file. Which should be possible ever since XP. On 2000 I think not all were signed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linux, here Ubuntu, you can use `chntpw`.

I did this:

```
sudo apt install chntpw
chntpw -e /path/to/windisk/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE
cat \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName
```

and was told that the version was `Windows 10 Home`. Note that the capitalization in the path may differ across versions, so look if it doesn't work. One plae also mentioned  a `RegBack` folder occurring int he path (sorry, I forgot where).

Additional details may be found through other keys. To list other keys in `CurrentVersion`,  while in `chntpw`, do

```
ls \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```